# How to create DDS file?

Tags: 3d-graphics, dds

What applications can I use to create *.dds files(DirectDraw Surface) under Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft [lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943990.aspx) tools such as the [DirectX Texture Editor (Dxtex.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219744.aspx) and the [Texture Conversion Tool (Texconv.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206243.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin for Gimp [gimp-dds](http://code.google.com/p/gimp-dds/) wich allows you to read and write DDS files easily.

Comment: OP has requested "under Windows", yet `gimp-dds` has another advantage: it is also available for Linux and actually included in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I used to like this free one from nVidia:

http://developer.nvidia.com/object/photoshop_dds_plugins.html

You might want to dig info here as well:

http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nv_texture_tools.html